# How to run cor.test() on two different dataframes

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to run cor.test() on two seperate dataframes but I am unsure how to proceed.

I have two example dataframes with identical columns (patients) but differing rows (bacteria and genes, respectively):

|  | 1C | 1L | 2C | 2L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Staphylococcus | 10 | 400 | 20 | 600 |
| Enterococcus | 15 | 607 | 39 | 800 |

|  | 1C | 1L | 2C | 2L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IL4 | 60 | 300 | 90 | 450 |
| IL8 | 30 | 600 | 54 | 750 |
| TNFA | 89 | 450 | 96 | 600 |

I want to run a spearman correlation test between both dataframes to identify if bacterial counts (abundance) are associated with increased expression of genes. So basically I want to test all bacteria against all genes.

I have tried running:

```
cor.test(df1, df2, method = "spearman", alternative = c("two.sided"))
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in cor.test.default(df1, df2, method = "spearman",  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Image produced from the code provided:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is trying to run a correlation on three variables when the function takes x and y vectors of the same length.

In order to compare all genes to all bacteria counts across subjects you have to get them into a tabular format the function can work with. You can use pivot_longer() from tidyr for that and then merge to join on subject.

```
Bacteria <- data.frame(name=c("Staph", "Enter"), C1=c(10,15), L1=c(400,607), C2=c(20,39), L2=c(600, 800))
Genes <- data.frame(name=c("IL4", "IL8", "TNFA"), C1=c(60,30,89), L1=c(300,600,450), C2=c(90,54,96), L2=c(450,750,600))

Bacteria <- pivot_longer(Bacteria, -1, names_to = "Subject", values_to="Counts")
Genes <- pivot_longer(Genes, -1, names_to = "Subject", values_to="Counts")

FullSet <- merge(Bacteria, Genes, by="Subject", suffixes = c(".Bac", ".Gene"))

cor.test(FullSet$Counts.Bac, FullSet$Counts.Gene, method="spearman", alternative=c("two.sided"))
```

Edit to create a nice looking corrplot with p-value matrix

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)

MakeStats <- function(x) {

result <- cor.test(x$Counts.Bac, x$Counts.Gene, method="spearman", alternative=c("two.sided"))
return(data.frame(Bacteria=x$name.Bac[1], Gene=x$name.Gene[1],    Estimate=result$estimate[1], PValue=result$p.value, row.names=NULL))
}

ListOfTests <- split(FullSet, list(FullSet$name.Bac, FullSet$name.Gene))
Results <- bind_rows(lapply(ListOfTests, MakeStats))
PValues <- Results[,-3]
Estimates <- Results[,-4]
Estimates <- pivot_wider(Estimates, id_cols="Gene", names_from="Bacteria", values_from="Estimate")
PValues <- pivot_wider(PValues, id_cols="Gene", names_from="Bacteria", values_from="PValue")

EstMatrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(Estimates[-1], row.names = Estimates$Gene))
PMatrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(PValues[-1], row.names = PValues$Gene))

corrplot(EstMatrix, method="square", p.mat = PMatrix, pch=8)
```

[image: Corrplot with PValues]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I noticed that the results are only giving me a single rho value and p value. I was aiming to get matrix with individual rho and p values for each comparison (e.g. staphylococcus vs IL4, Staphylococcus vs IL8, etc). How would I do that?

Comment: No problem. There are a lot of ways but I gave a few examples you could use to split and process the data, hopefully that helps - I think you are aiming for what is in option three.

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I was after!! Would you know how to format that ResultsMatrix to make it compatible with corrplot?

Comment: `test <- filter(FullSet, name.Bac=="Staph") %>% select(Counts.Bac, Counts.Gene); corrplot(cor(test), method="number")` you could do something like that filtering for gene name or bacteria with corrplot. To run corrplot you just need to pass two vectors into `cor(x,y)`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I was actually hoping to create a plot like the one shown in Figure 3, A of this paper https://genomemedicine.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s13073-020-0710-2.pdf. So basically pick maybe the top 50 most significant interactions based on p.value and plot the gene/bacterial interactions as they did. Sorry I am completely new to this.

Comment: No problem. You have to add a correlation matrix and pvalue matrix to get that effect so I edited a new approach that is better organized toward giving corrplot the input it needs. I assume it's working but the rho values are all 1 with the tiny amount of data. Please see [Corrplot Introduction on Cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) for info on additional tweaks.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is perfect and you have made my life so much easier. All the best!

Comment: Hello again! I just wanted a follow up. This project was put on hold but now I have resumed I have used the code you provided which has worked as intended. The only issue is it hasn't produced significance stars, instead there are black lines connecting each square. I have put an example of what I mean in the original question

Comment: Sorry disregard, I just noticed that it is just the star signs a too large making it look like connected lines

Comment: very helpful answer this I was also looking for